# Why is English used internationally?

Tags: international

Why is English so globally prevalent and pervasive on the web?
Is this because Britishers ruled the world decades ago, thereby disseminating English to those respective regions?

Comment: I would also look to the USA: Hollywood, pop music, technology and science. When the United Kingdom/Great Britain had an empire (Victorian era) the lingua franca was French. But it would be extremely difficult to summarise an answer in a couple of lines. Your question is interesting but too broad for this Q&A site.

Comment: Apparently, just apparently, a small set of grammatical rules, in comparison with French, German, Spanish, etc. So the start :-)) is easy ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA, 30,000 characters sounds like more than enough to put the main points down. I'd love to read a continuation of your answer!

Comment: I have (decades ago) read claims that in part it's due to the flexibility of English, and it's ability to exist side-by-side with other languages.

Comment: English is a language of communication. English is not enshrined as a National Treasure as French, Russian, German. Native English speakers will helpfully talk to you even if you don't speak it perfectly. French and Russians are forever correcting bad grammar, so it's difficult to talk to them. English is the language of the democracies and capitalism and economic wealth and military power which non-English speakers find attractive.

Answer (score 2):

(I freely admit that my response better qualifies as a comment than an answer, but it won't fit in the space of a comment.)

Yes, I think your explanation of how English became a lingua franca (or world language) is basically correct, though perhaps your explanation is an over-simplification.

During the age of imperialism, Britain's empire spanned from Africa to India to China, plus of course the colonies in North America and Australia. As a result, today English is the most wide-spread language in the world. It's spoken in 54 countries. French is spoken in 38, Arabic in 27, Spanish in 20, and the rest pale in comparison. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_widely_spoken_languages_%28by_number_of_countries) for stats.)

Of course, if you look at population the picture is different. Only around 5% of the world's population are native speakers of English. More people speak Spanish, and many more people speak Mandarin. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers) for stats.)

Comment: Nice answer, but would you kindly provide sources?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. I'll edit the response to include links.